# MySQL query taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, phpmyadmin

My MySQL query is taking around 20 minutes to execute which I feel is excessive.

```
SELECT 
  hyp_id,MAX( player_count ) AS MAXPLAYERCOUNT
  , MAX( viewer_count ) AS MAXVIEWERCOUNT
  , SUM( player_count ) AS TOTPLAYER
  , SUM( viewer_count ) AS TOTVIEWER 
FROM player_count_log 
WHERE 
  DATE(added_time) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY hyp_id 
ORDER BY  hyp_id
```

The `player_count_log` table contains over 63 million records with ~18k added every hour.

Here are screenshots of db and indexes

[image: screenshot of the database]

[image: screenshot of the indexes]

Comment: Lots of indexes, did you check if an index is actually used? First I would rewrite the WHERE: `WHERE added_time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS TIMESTAMP)`, you probably don't need `AND added_time < CAST(CURDATE() + 1 AS TIMESTAMP)` as there should be no future rows.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to see the used indexes and other information about the query plan.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE(added_time) = CURDATE()
```

is the root of some of the evil

Do not "hide" a column `(added_time)` inside a function (`DATE`) if want an index to be used.

If `added_time` is a `DATE`, then you can simply do

```
added_time = CURDATE()
```

If it is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, then do

```
added_time >= CURDATE() AND
added_time  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Then your `INDEX(added_time)` can be used.